# for loop error while dropping a column in dataframe

Tags: r

I am facing some error in r. Please do find the below code

```
for (i in 1:64) {
    if (sum(is.na(prop_train$nam[i]))/length(prop_train$nam[i]) > .3) {
        prop_train$nam[i] <- NULL
    }
}
```

about code: I am writing this code for dropping the columns which have NA more than 30%  in data frame,

but I am facing this

```
error:Error in if (sum(is.na(prop_train$nam[i]))/length(prop_train$nam[i]) >  :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed In addition: Warning message: In is.na(prop_train$nam[i]) :
```

Comment: provide reproducible example and format your code properly

Comment: If `prop_train` is a dataframe, you need to remove the `$nam`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```
prop_train <- data.frame(col1=c(1,2,NA,NA,NA),
                         col2=c(3,4,5,6,NA),
                         col3=c(7,8,9,10,11))

prop_train_new <- prop_train[ lapply( prop_train, function(x) sum(is.na(x)) / length(x) ) < 0.3 ]
```

*Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem :)*